# Need expert views over this enterprise react project redux implementation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, architecture

Recently I joined a team for a react project, would like to know your "to the point" views over this current redux architecture implementation in this enterprise project.

There are various modules (all has similar approach), let's take one called `Search`, structure as below.

[image]

Here `Page` Component is the root component which has `mapStateToProps` & `mapDispatchToProps` So it consists all further componets as per the image, here every state is passed through props in all components, goes from `Page` till `Basic Search` via `Form` -> `Search` -> `Basic Search` & vice-versa for passing back. So props drilling.
All components are dependent on `Page` components for `state`, all componets are passed `states` via `props` from `page` till end.

Please let me know if you think, I should explain it further, I can do so. Share your expertise.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything more about the dataflow, generally speaking [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is the react construct that helps in avoiding repeated, deep prop pass-throughs. It's good for accessing fairly static, "global" data like a user session ID, etc.